# Hive - Optimising a self-join

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Let's say I have the following query:

```
select a.model, a.engine_size, b.engine_size from (

  select model, engine_size
  from cars
  where number_of_doors = 4
) a

inner join (

  select model, engine_size
  from cars
  where number_of_doors = 4
) b

on (a.model = b.model);
```

I'm repeating a subquery here. I'm just wondering if the following is more 'optimal' or will the repeated subquery's result automatically be cached?

```
with features as (

  select model, engine_size
  from cars
  where number_of_doors = 4
)

select a.model, a.engine_size, b.engine_size
from features a
inner join features b
on (a.model = b.model);
```

Is either of these going to be more efficient?

Comment: why do you need subquery, also not sure why you need engine_size twice, you can get same with single query,   select model, engine_size, engine_size from cars where number_of_doors =4

Comment: It's an example that I pulled out of the air. The question is more to do with how hive optimizes subqueries.

Comment: sorry confused. is the question to optimise self-join or subquery?bcz same sub-query repeated twice to make a self-join is resulting in unwanted complex query for a simple one. would be good if you may clarify the question with real example.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by doing a self join but the scenario doesn't make any sense

```
select a.model, a.engine_size,b.engine_size
from   cars a 
join   cars b 
on     (a.model = b.model)
where  a.number_of_doors = 4
```